# How should I share the same NuGet package among multiple C# solutions?

Tags: c#, json.net, nuget

I am working with Newtonsoft.Json (a.k.a. Json.net) now and multiple C# solutions need to reference it. Seems the most convenient and widely-used way is to install Newtonsoft.Json with NuGet package manager. But I find that the package is installed in the solution root directory (anyway, the installation is based on a given solution) and its size cannot just be neglected (a bit over 10M), so I wonder if there is an elegant way to share this package among different C# solutions.

I searched Google and found few satisfying results (maybe it's because I didn't express my requirement properly); the only sound answer is to create a .nuget folder both in the directory and in the solution and fill it with a NuGet.config file, as follows:

1. Create a .nuget folder in the root of the solution (by entering ".nuget.", actually)
2. Inside that folder, create a file NuGet.config.
3. In Visual Studio 2015, right click on the solution and add a new solution directory called “.nuget”
4. Right click on that folder and select to add an existing file and select the NuGet.config file created in (2).
5. Add content like this inside the NuGet.config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <solution>
    <add key="disableSourceControlIntegration" value="true" />
  </solution>
  <config>
    <add key="repositoryPath" value="E:\JsonExamples\C#Examples\UseJsonInCSharp\packages" />
  </config>
</configuration>
```

6. Restart Visual Studio 2015.

But that didn't work because the using directive

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
```

is still not recognized! Maybe there are something else that must be done, which isn't known to me but is common sense to veterans? Or perhaps this is because the version of the  Newtonsoft.Json is too new for this to work? Can somebody help me? thanks a lot!

One more word: I'm currently using VS 2017, but I only found answers related to VS 2015, so I wonder the previous approach, if somehow works on VS 2015, will ever work for VS 2017.

Comment: Two suggestions: **(1)** Put nuget.config in the repo root (e.g. with .gitignore if you're using Git) and forget about the .nuget folder. That's primarily for use with nuget.exe, which is obsolete for package restore purposes. **(2)** Try using a relative path for the packages folder. That path will be relative to the nuget.config that specifies it. If you specify "..\packages" and you have other projects whose root folders are at the same level, they can share that packages folder, which will also be a sibling to the project roots. Once that works, try an absolute path if you want.

Comment: If at all possible, switch to using the `PackageReference` element instead of `packages.config`, especially if you can switch to SDK-style projects. It causes the reference to be made to the cache folder, `%USERPROFILE%\.nuget\packages` by default, so no solution copies are ever made.

Answer (score 2):

Lets first clarify some things about NuGet and references in projects:

1. The job of references in project is to tell what external code this projects must look into - you can NOT go around this, you have to make a reference to Newtonsoft.Json in every project you want to use it.
2. The job of NuGet is to download/restore the nuget in some folder - the default "dumb" setting for old pre NuGet 4 versions is to make a seperate packages folder in every solution. Lets Focus on how to make this smarter.

**Option 1 (Recommended) - Migrate everything to PackageReference**

It is available since NuGet 4 in VS 2017+ (i recommend at least VS 2017 15.7+ which got wizard for automatic migration from older nuget versions). This is the most clean way of referencing NuGets since PackageReference in project does not hardcode NuGet download location. Instead it leaves this decision to local NuGet settings. By Default it is set to "%USERPROFILE%\.nuget\packages". No nuget package is duplicated, it acts as global cache for this computer. To force all new project to use PackageReference by default you must modify NuGet.config, here is how: [Defaulting Package Management to PackageReference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49160858/defaulting-package-management-to-packagereference)

**Option 2 - specify common NuGet location for all project in the same repository**

NuGet config settings are loaded per Solution. Having a common config file for NuGet is recommended even if you use PackageReference since download location is just one of many settings you might want to centrally manage for all Solutions (the other popular one is a setting which external NuGet repositories you want to use). NuGet download location setting is ignored by new PackageReference so it is safe to use it in mix scenario. VERY IMPORTANT, **projects using this old NuGet use hardcoded reference to NuGet folder, so everytime you change this NuGet location setting you have to manually fix all NuGet references in your every project** (by editing .csproj file manually or be deleting and re-adding NuGets), so chose wisely and do not change.


**Details on how to correctly set global NuGet.config:**

So first let me explain how shared NuGet.config settings work. NuGet scans all NuGet.config files from solution location up the hierarchy to root drive (it also check all .nuget folders). If multiple config files are detected it takes the one closest to solution. So for example you have "C:\Code\Repository1\Project1\Solution1.sln". If you want to have common NuGet settings for every solution in Repository1 put config file to a location like this "C:\Code\Repository1\NuGet.config". Also make sure this is the only config file inside whole Repository1 folder. Next step is to decide where to download all packages, for example "C:\Code\Repository1\NuGetPackages". To make everything work dynamically on all computers put relative path inside NuGet.config like this:

> add key="repositoryPath" value="NuGetPackages"